# Android Garbage Collector behavior

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Ok, I know there was a few similar questions, but I couldn't find nowhere pure facts about `GC` in android.

When system calls `GC`?

What `GC` in android counts as not needed?

Why `GC` skips bitmaps?

Sample of code that shows how we can bypass `GC`? (Object = null ?)

What does `GC` do with not needed object?

Other important facts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

****   When system calls GC? What GC in android counts as not needed?   ****

There are at least 5 different ways a garbage collector is called in android one of the common and I know you always see this when you look at the `logcat` is

```
GC_CUNCURRENT
```

it is a `concurrent collection` that is triggered when the heap start to fill up.

```
GC_FOR_MALLOC
```

it is called when `GC_CUNCURRENT` was not able to completed in time and that the heap is full and also device need to allocate more memory then this is triggered, the garbage collection directly  executed.

```
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC
```

this is only called in `API below HONEYCOMB` where it is triggered when you release memory to the Bitmap pixel data by calling `recycle()` method of it.

```
GC_HPROF_DUMP_HEAP
```

this is called when you create an **hprof** file from the `DDMS` for `memory analyzation` or locating the `memory leak`.

```
GC_IMPLICIT
```

now this is called when you are calling the garbage collector itself through `System.gc()`, **Beware:** avoid calling this and that you should trust the `garbage collector`.

**Why GC skips bitmaps?**

That is because you need to implicitly call the recycle method of the Bitmap to call the garbage collector to recycle the bitmap pixel data of it. Every bitmap from `HONEY and above` are store in the `dalvik heap`.

**What does GC do with not needed object?**

As long as the object have `reference` somewhere it wont be garbage collected and will result to memory leak, you can use DDMS to check the memory leak of your application.